# How to for loop CURL commands?

Tags: bash, curl, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am using Watson's Speech-To-Text Lite service and I am trying to find a way to automate the loading of new audio files to transcribe. I am very new to Bash and so I'm unclear of even the more rudimentary terms - so I'm finding the problem hard to find a solution for.

For a single use-case, I run the following file (my API key omitted with 'MY APIKEY')

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey: MY APIKEY" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary "@audiofile_1.flac" "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&speaker_labels=true" > C:/Users/outputpath/output_1.txt
```

What I am essentially trying to achieve is to overcome having to manually type and retype the names of the audio files and output. So if I had three (or more) audio files (i.e. audiofile_1, 2, and 3.flac), i would like to create an output file corresponding to each audio file -  Some psuedo-code that might help explain what I mean would be

```
files = [file_1, file_2, file_3]

for file_x in files:
    run curl command
    save as output_x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. You just need to learn some shell syntax:

```
files=("file_1" "file_2" "file_3")

for file_x in "${files[@]}"
do
    curl -X POST -u "apikey: MY APIKEY" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary "@${file_x}" "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&speaker_labels=true" > "C:/Users/outputpath/${file_x}.txt"
done
```

First you create the `files` array with your list of files. Then, you iterate over those files and run the `curl` command on each of them.

Comment: Hi Poshi, I have run your code but am getting errors. Specifically, the output is saying "script1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `&'" which I assumed to be the opening speech marks at the beginning of the for loop, but when I close them off I get EOF errors.

Comment: Ops! There's a typo... colon/quote exchanged. Well, I also forgot the do/done keywords XD I just edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm running the amended code but still getting errors. Specifically, 'testscript1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
estscript1.sh: line 3: do'
Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Comment: Nope. I don't know what is testscript1.sh, so cannot tell you what could be there. Anyways, given your error message, I see a probably unexpected carriage return (`\r`). Check if you have proper line endings for your operating system in that script.

Comment: OK great - turns out it was a problem between Windows and Unix (another distinction I am largely unfamiliar with). Changing the EOL conversion in Notepad++ corrected it. Thanks for your help....testscript1.sh was the file I had copied your code into. It looks like those original errors have been solved. :)